# Using data.table j to fill a matrix (more generally to interact with outside variables)

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to benefit from data.table fast grouping to fill a matrix (or do other stuff externally from the data.table).

For example, I have a data.table like this:

```
DT = data.table(x_id=rep(c(1,2),c(100,100)),x_value = rnorm(200))
setkey(DT,x_id)
```

(representing two different time-series)

I want to put the same information a matrix of 100 rows and 2 columns.
I tried

```
A = matrix(NA,100,2)
DT[,{A[,.GRP] = x_value},by=x_id]
```

But it doesn't work. This raises two questions for me: (I was unable to find help in the doc)

1) Is there a nice way (without loops) to transform the data.table into the matrix.

2) Generally speaking, can we assign value to outside variables in the **j** environment.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DT[,A[,.GRP] <<- x_value,by=x_id]
```

`<<-` assigns through to the global environment, which is what you need to do since the `data.table` expressions are evaluated in a child environment that doesn't contain `A`.

I would add this is a fairly odd way to use `data.table`.  If you are guaranteed that each group has the same number of rows, then all you need to do is (assuming you have already sorted by `x_id`:

```
A <- matrix(DT[, x_value], 100)
```

Which takes advantage of the underlying vector-like nature of matrices.

Comment: You're right it is a bit odd. Thanks for the answer, the first line might be useful in other context anyway!